# What does "SQL specification for referential triggered actions" mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following tables for a relational database that keeps track of student enrollment in courses and the books adopted for each course:

- STUDENT (Ssn, Name, Major, Bdate)
- COURSE (Course#, Cname, Dept)
- ENROLL (Ssn, Course#, Quarter, Grade)
- BOOK_ADOPTION (Course#, Quarter, Book_isbn)
- TEXT (Book_isbn, Book_title, Publisher, Author)

Specify the foreign keys for this schema and write down the necessary statements for creating the above tables incorporating SQL specification for referential triggered actions, wherever necessary.

PS: Also, please provide details about what the "Quarter" column means in the "ENROLL".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exercise is asking you to write the tables specification in DDL (to be more specific), paying attention to foreign keys specification and also on the necessary declarations to instruct the engine to handle updates/deletes of rows which already have related child records on other tables.

P.S.: Quarter is a common period of time of 3 months.

Comment: DDL is not SQL?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, you are right. I edited my answer to mean to be more specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that a row with a key must exist prior to inserting a row into a table with a foreign key column.

Comment: SORRY for the edit - Removed the upvote as the other answer by Little Santi is better, and includes the point of deletion of rows in child table too!